# Shopware6 cache invalidation with Varnish

Tags: varnish, shopware, shopware6

I'm testing Varnish cache integration with Shopware6.

During Settings > Caches & Indexes > Clear caches Varnish is not involved at all.
Result: cache in Varnish is not purged and store continue to serve pages cached in Varnish.

Am I missing something or is Shopware lacking of this part of integration?

Answer (score 1):

did you configure shopware, and set the path for the varnish?

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/infrastructure/reverse-http-cache#configure-shopware

if shopware dosen't know the proxy, i't can't be purged.

Comment: Yes reverse_proxy - hosts, is configured indeed single product invalidation is working, I can see the BAN command on Varnish log. Complete cache invalidation (including bin/console cache:clear) doesn't send any command to Varnish

Comment: if that's the case it think you have to register your to the cache clear action and fire a BAN request by your self.
The Class would be Shopware\Core\Framework\Adapter\Cache\CacheClearer

But maybe there is a shopware <> varnish hero who already solved this :-)